# I cannot get a return code from my javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I assign the following to a button on a modal. When the user clicks
on the button it calls submitHandler.

```
   var btn = {
        'Submit & Close': function (win) {
            var rc = submitHandler(oLink.$link, $modal);
            $('#createLink').prop('disabled', false);
        },
        'Close': function (win) {
            $modal.closeModal();
            $('#createLink').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    }
```

My submitHandler looks like this:

```
    function submitHandler($link, $modal) {

  if (!$form.valid || $form.valid()) {
        $submitBt.disableBt();
        $modal.removeBlockMessages()
            .blockMessage('Contacting Server, please wait ... ', { type: 'loading' });
        $.ajax({
            url: oSubmit.href,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $form.serializeArray()
        })
        .done(function (json, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            json = json || {};
            if (json.success) {
                submitSuccessModal(oSubmit, json);
                return true;
            } else {
                submitFailModal(oSubmit, json);
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        })

    }
```

When I check in the debugger submitHandler runs but when I look at the value of 
rc it is undefined.

Is there something obvious I am missing. I simply cannot get rc to equal
anything other than "undefined".

**Update:**

I added in an actual section of the code. I am wondering if it could be the ajax call that's causing this? Note that I can follow the code with the debugger to the return true; line.

Comment: Could it be the `:` instead of the `;`?

Comment: Is the `:` a typo in the question?

Comment: Sorry that was a type. The actual code has a semicolon.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return value from ajax call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632039/return-value-from-ajax-call) see [SLaks' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1632088/139010) (do not use `async: false`).

Answer (score 5):

Statements are terminated with semicolon, not colon.

```
function submitHandler($link, $modal) {
   return true;
}          // ↑
```

Comment: How did you type `↑` in your post? +1 for quick find.

Comment: Sorry. That was a type. My actual code does use a semicolon. I am totally confused as to why it might not work.

Comment: @Vega http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2191/index.htm or just type `&uarr;` in a non-code block, then Ctrl-C Ctrl-V.

Comment: @MattBall Thanks..Also the OP question is about async return value from ajax call.

Comment: @Vega yes, it's the typical "ajax is asynchronous problem," looking for a dup to close as.

Answer (score 2):

Check the semicolon at the end of the return statement in the handler.

```
function submitHandler($link, $modal) {
   return true;
}
```